# How to open PDF files in browser if Chrono is installed?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download-manager

Along with advatages of download managers like [Chrono](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=en), I also get a lot of disadvatages. One of them is that I cannot open PDF files in browser anymore -- I can only download it and then need to find it within Chrono tab to open.

Is it possible to avoid this? Can I open PDF files in browser?

Comment: If you right click on the pdf file, can't you select the default program to open it? I believe if you select it once, it will be applicable to all the others (I believe there is a checkbox for that, at least on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

It was not problem of download manager it's a new setting of Chrome browser, https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en

From that page:

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More More and
  then Settings.
- At the bottom, click Advanced.
- Under "Privacy and security," click Content settings.
- Near the bottom, click PDF documents.
- Turn off Download PDF files instead of automatically
  opening them in Chrome.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.